# Matplotlib Histogram: Green and Blue Bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, bins

I'm using pyplot to make a histogram. Here is approximately what I'm doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

A = {my dataset as a dictionary: different numbers and their frequencies}
numbers = A.keys()
frequencies = A.values()
plot = np.transpose(np.array([[numbers,frequencies]])
n = <my bins-value here>
pl.hist(plot,bins=n,log=True)
pl.show()
```

I have noticed that, regardless of the number of bins I specify, the second bin is always green, like below. Why is it green? What does this mean? How do I prevent this from happening?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really use `hist` that way.  `hist` *computes* value frequencies given the raw data.  You have already computed the frequencies, and you're trying to pass them to `hist`, but that's not the input `hist` needs.  When you pass in a two-dimensional array, as you're doing, `hist` displays multiple histograms, one for each column.  This is [documented](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist):

> Multiple data can be provided via x as a list of datasets of potentially different length ([x0, x1, ...]), or as a 2-D ndarray in which each column is a dataset.

So you're getting one bar graph (the blue ones) for your labels, and another (the green ones) for their counts.  Presumably all the green ones are lumped together because their range is much smaller.

If you generated your frequencies from raw data, you can pass that raw data to `hist` to get your histogram.  If you only have the histogram data, you should use matplotlib's `bar` function to make a bar graph yourself using the histogram data.  However, you'd have to bin it yourself.  The bottom line is that you can either let `hist` do everything, or nothing: you can have it compute the frequencies and the bins and do the plot, or you can compute the frequencies and the bins and do the plot, but you can't just compute the frequencies yourself and have `hist` just do the binning and the plot.